# How can I create a RadioButtonList in a MVC View via HTML class ( Razor syntax )

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I need to show my list in a RadioButtonList , some thing like this:
@Html.RadioButtonList("FeatureList", new SelectList(ViewBag.Features))
But as you know there is no RadioButtonList class in HTML Helper class and when I use :
@Html.RadioButton("FeatureList", new SelectList(ViewBag.Features))
it shows me a blank list!
// Controller codes :

```
 public ActionResult Rules()
        {

            ViewBag.Features = (from m in Db.Features where m.ParentID == 3 select m.Name);
            return View();

        }
```

Answer (score 12):

`Html.RadioButton` does not take `(string, SelectList)` arguments, so I suppose the blank list is expected ;)

You could 1)

Use a `foreach` over your radio button values in your model and use the `Html.RadioButton(string, Object)` overload to iterate your values

```
// Options could be a List<string> or other appropriate 
// data type for your Feature.Name
@foreach(var myValue in Model.Options) {
    @Html.RadioButton("nameOfList", myValue)
}
```

or 2)

Write your own helper method for the list--might look something like this (I've never written one like this, so your mileage may vary)

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonList(this HtmlHelper helper, 
    string NameOfList, List<string> RadioOptions) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // put a similar foreach here
    foreach(var myOption in RadioOptions) {
        sb.Append(helper.RadioButton(NameOfList, myOption));
    }

    return new MvcHtmlString(sb.ToString());
}
```

And then call your new helper in your view like (assuming Model.Options is still List or other appropriate data type)

```
@Html.RadioButtonList("nameOfList", Model.Options)
```