# Asp.net mvc ListBox recommendations?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-mvc

I'm converting a asp.net application over to asp.net mvc that uses a lot of listboxes, specifically the RadListBox from Telerik. The ListBox that comes with mvc is very basic and I'm wondering if anyone has come across a better alternative.  I'm really looking for the ability to reorder, add, and delete from the client.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems at the moment there is no special tool (with professional features like Telerik tools) for MVC. However I suggest you using extension methods as it was [my problem already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132474/how-can-i-create-a-radiobuttonlist-in-a-mvc-view-via-html-class-razor-syntax):

And also you can replace it with a [Telerik MVC dropdownlist][2]

[2]: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/combobox which is Free!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  How would I replace it with a Telerik MVC dropdownlist?  The drop down list only displays one item...