# radioButtolListFor helper not required - mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, data-annotations

I'm refferd to this post [article stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132474/how-can-i-create-a-radiobuttonlist-in-a-mvc-view-via-html-class-razor-syntax)
and this [second article stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512809/has-anyone-implement-radiobuttonlistfort-for-asp-net-mvc)

and I'm using the RadioButtonListFor

```
public static MvcHtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> listOfValues,
        IDictionary<string, object> radioHtmlAttributes = null,
        string ulClass = null)
        {
            ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);

            if (radioHtmlAttributes == null)
                radioHtmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary();

            TagBuilder ulTag = new TagBuilder("ul");
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ulClass))
                ulTag.MergeAttribute("class", ulClass);

            if (listOfValues != null)
            {
                // Create a radio button for each item in the list 
                foreach (SelectListItem item in listOfValues)
                {

                    // Generate an id to be given to the radio button field 
                    var id = string.Format("{0}_{1}", metaData.PropertyName, item.Value);

                    if (!radioHtmlAttributes.ContainsKey("id"))
                        radioHtmlAttributes.Add("id", id);
                    else
                        radioHtmlAttributes["id"] = id;

                    // Create and populate a radio button using the existing html helpers 
                    var label = htmlHelper.Label(id, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Text));
                    var radio = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(expression, item.Value, radioHtmlAttributes).ToHtmlString();

                    // Create the html string that will be returned to the client 
                    // e.g. <input data-val="true" data-val-required="You must select an option" id="TestRadio_1" name="TestRadio" type="radio" value="1" /><label for="TestRadio_1">Line1</label> 
                    ulTag.InnerHtml += string.Format("<li>{0}{1}</li>", radio, label);
                }
            }

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(ulTag.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
        }
```

My problem is that the radio button is required and when I don't check a radio button I Have an error the field is mandatory, how can I disable this ?? (In my view model I don't use the dataAnnotation Required)

this a part of my viewModel:

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
    {
            #region country
            public string Country { get; set; }
            private string CountryLabel { get; set; }
            public ConfigurationParamValue CountryParam { get; set; }
            #endregion

            #region civilty
            public int Civility { get; set; }
            public ConfigurationParamValue CivilityParam { get; set; }
            public string CivilityLabel { get; set; }
            public List<Civility> ListCivilitys { get; set; }
            #endregion

}
```

and this is a part of my view:

```
<div id="city">
            <div class="editor-label" style="@visibleCivility">
                  @Html.GetResource(Model.Category,Model.IsLocal,Constantes.CivilityLabel)
                <div style="@mandatoryCivility">*</div>
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               @Html.RadioButtonListFor(m => m.Civility, new SelectList(Model.ListCivilitys,"ID","Name")) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Civility)
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the model class nevertheless?

Comment: You probably have a required field validator?

Comment: I edited the question to add some detailed, i don't use the required validator

Comment: Maybe there is a validation logic in your controller?

Comment: No valid logic in my controller, the problem is th html created by the new helper contain: `<input data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Civility doit être un nombre." data-val-required="The Civility field is required." id="Civility_1" name="Civility" type="radio" value="1" />` and i'm not using required attribute

Comment: Sackoverflow? Stacoverflow? Really!?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver i don't understand your question?

Comment: @user1428798 Did you find an answer for this question? I mean other than the one below from @-trexium

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure why, but it seems the HtmlHelper.RadioButtonFor method returns a tag including the "data-val-required"-attribute.
If you simply don't want this field to be validated at all you can disable ClientValidation for just this element like in this example:

```
 @{Html.EnableClientValidation(false);}
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.MyRadioButton)
 @{Html.EnableClientValidation(true);}
```

However, i had this problem and wanted the requirement to be dependant on another tag. One solution that I used for this problem was to create a regex to remove the "data-val-required"-attribute in our code.
Which look something like this:

```
var radioButton = htmlHelper.RadioButtonFor(*parameters*);
var requiredAttribute = *check if required attribute was set manually*;
if (requiredAttribute == null)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("(data-val-required=\"[a-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ \\s \\. 0-9]*\")");
    radioButton = regex.Replace(radioButton, "");
}
```

This solved my problem in a simple and generic way.